# Cambiar el texto del botón al hacer click en él - jQuery

Tags: jquery, show, hide

Tengo un **botón**

```
<div class="boton_anadir_cabana" class="table-responsive" align="left">
    <font face="verdana">
        <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña" /></b>
    </font>
</div>
```

con un texto por defecto "**Añadir cabaña**", al **hacer clic** en él se me abre un formulario desplegable y si vuelvo a hacer click de nuevo en el **botón** ese formulario se oculta, así sucesivamente gracias al método **toogle()**, que muestra (**show()**) y oculta (**hide()**) alternativamente los botones.

El **formulario** que se abre/cierra tiene como **name** y como **id**:

```
name="anadir_cabana" id="anadir_cabana"
```

Deseo que se cambie el texto dependiendo si está abierto o está cerrado:

1. Si hago click en el botón y abro el formulario, el texto cambia a
   "Ocultar cabaña"
2. Si el formulario está oculto, el texto cambia a "Añadir cabaña"

**¿Por qué no cambia el texto?**

**Código jQuery intentado:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide() --> ocultar ||| show() --> mostrar ||| toggle() --> ocultar/mostrar
    $('#anadir_cabana').hide();
    $("#nueva_cabana").on("click", function() {
        $('#anadir_cabana').toggle(
        // Primer click
        function(e){ 
            $(this).text('Añadir nueva cabaña');
            e.preventDefault();
        }, // Separamos las dos funciones con una coma

        // Segundo click
        function(e){ 
            $(this).text('Ocultar añadir cabaña');
            e.preventDefault();
        } );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias cosas a corregir.

El método `toggle` no recibe como argumentos una función para ejecutar después de mostrar y otra para después de ocultar. Existen varias posibilidades pero la que creo que tratas de utilizar recibe un primer argumento que indica la duración de la transición y un segundo argumento con una función a ejecutar una vez que haya concluido (independientemente de si se ha mostrado u ocultado el elemento).

Por otra parte, cuando se ejecuta esta función pasada como argumento al `toggle`, `this` hace referencia al elemento que se esta ocultando o mostrando, no al botón que generó el evento click.

Además para modificar el texto de un botón se utiliza el método `val`, no el `text`. Fíjate que incluso en el HTML estableces el texto del botón en el atributo `value`.

En la función de callback del `toggle` deberías comprobar si el elemento está visible o no para decidir qué texto ponerle al botón.

Algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anadir_cabana').hide();
    $("#nueva_cabana").on("click", function(e) {
      var $boton = $(this);
      $('#anadir_cabana').toggle(500,
        function(){
          $boton.val($(this).is(':visible')
              ? 'Ocultar añadir cabaña'
              : 'Añadir nueva cabaña');
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anadir_cabana">Cabaña</div>
<div class="boton_anadir_cabana" class="table-responsive" align="left">
    <font face="verdana">
        <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña" /></b>
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: si yo quisiera cambiar la propiedad onClic ademas de val, inclusive si quiero reempalzar el boton por un enlace <a>, ¿como lo haria? gracias de antemano :)